# как можно сделать чтобы npc "видел" и не "видел" игрока?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```py
def can_see_hero(self):
    for p in platforms:
        #вычисление расположения х игрока и npc
        if hero.rect.x+hero.a <= self.rect.x:
            if hero.rect.x >= p.rect.x+p.w:
                if hero.rect.y <= self.rect.y:
#вычисления расположения у игрока и платформы
                    if hero.rect.y <= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=True
                    if hero.rect.y >= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=False

                if hero.rect.y > self.rect.y:
                    if hero.rect.y <= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=False
                    if hero.rect.y >= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=True
            if hero.rect.x+hero.a<=p.rect.x:
                if hero.rect.y <= self.rect.y:
                    if hero.rect.y <= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=True
                    if hero.rect.y >= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=False

                if hero.rect.y > self.rect.y:
                    if hero.rect.y <= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=False
                    if hero.rect.y >= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=True
        if hero.rect.x >= self.rect.x:
            if hero.rect.x >= p.rect.x+p.w:
                if hero.rect.y <= self.rect.y:
                    if hero.rect.y <= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=True
                    if hero.rect.y >= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=False

                if hero.rect.y > self.rect.y:
                    if hero.rect.y <= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=False
                    if hero.rect.y >= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=True
            if hero.rect.x+hero.a<=p.rect.x:
                if hero.rect.y <= self.rect.y:
                    if hero.rect.y <= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=True
                    if hero.rect.y >= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=False

                if hero.rect.y > self.rect.y:
                    if hero.rect.y <= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=False
                    if hero.rect.y >= p.rect.y:
                        self.see=True
```

Можете мне указать на логические ошибки?

- hero-игрок
- p-платформа
- self-npc

Comment: сделайте переменную видит=0. как координаты игрока минус координаты нпс ниже радиуса видит, то видит =1  . если видит==1 то погнали мочить.

Comment: Дело в том что я ещё использую блоки, которые должни ограничивать обзор для npc

Comment: радиус ограничен блоком (r=скока там до блока)....и что это меняет ?

Comment: я не знаю как это сделать :(

Comment: тогда план б.сделайте блоки,наступая на которые включается 'видит'

Comment: Это будет выглядеть не очень. Я же делаю что то вроде рп шутера. И мне нужно нормальное "зрение" для моих npc

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что ты взялся за задачу, которая тебе не по зубам. Если ты не знаешь, как сделать то, что советуют товарищи в коментах, то рп шутер ты не потянеш. Попробуй сперва что-то попроще реализовать

Comment: мне это по зубам, мне просто сложно визуализировать, то что я хочу :(                                       если бы мне было легко визуализировать, то что мне надо, я бы был рад моему результату.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте нарисуем и рассмотрим картинку (проекция вида сверху - top-down).

[image: npc-view]

Здесь:

- красные кружочки - это npc
- зеленый - игрок
- закрашенный прямоугольник - стена/преграда (ПР)
- треугольники - область видимости/зрения npc (ТВ)
- черные линии от npc до игрока - линии видимости (ЛВ)
- маленькие красные точки - пересечение ЛВ и преграды

Тогда алгоритм выделения адреналина у npc будет такой:

1. Пока есть, берем очередного npc
2. Проверяем, попадает ли игрок в ТВ данного npc
3. Если да, то

   3.1 Последовательно получаем и проверяем все ПР(через проверку характерных точек ПР), лежащие внутри ТВ данного npc. Проверка пересечения ЛВ с преградой, осуществляется наличием точек пересечения ЛВ и сторон ПР (или других характерных линий - диагоналей, срединных линий и тому подобное)

   3.2 Если точки пересечения ЛВ и ПР имеются, то npc игрока не видит и it keeps calm. Переходим к п.1

   3.3 Иначе выделяется адреналин и начинается action
4. Если нет, переходим к п.1

Answer (score 0):

очень сложно, а пайтон говорит постой код лучше. есть отличная формула из тригонометрии на определение принадлежит ли точка кругу. Вот пример функции которая определяет вошел ли персонаж в тригерную зону, если да, то турель начинает стрелять.

```
def check_in(self):
    r = 200
    if (player.rect.centerx - self.rect.centerx) ** 2 + (player.rect.centery - self.rect.centery) ** 2 <= r * r:
        self.shoot()
```

Comment: в вашей формуле не учитываются платформы, которые могут скрыть обзор

Comment: потому что формула из игры жанра top-down shooter

Comment: Я в принцепе мог бы добавить к вашему ответу "понимание" где стены, но я не знаю как сделать понимарие где они :(

Comment: Ну а так это может быть ответом на половину

Comment: тогда  используй луч. как только персонаж попадает в игровую локацию, черти от нпс к нему линию, добавь расстояние его "зрения", и условие если вдруг луч пересек платформу